Visual Studio screen flickers on mouse clicks
I am experiencing a problem where my Visual Studio screen flickers or flashes whenever I click or moveover the mouse. This issue is specific to Visual Studio and occurs only on the connected screen.
Here are the details of my situation:
I have tried updating my graphics card drivers to the latest version, but the problem persists.
The flickering happens on different screens, cables, and outputs. I have tested both USB and HDMI outputs of my PC.
I have tried Visual Studio 2022 and 2019, and the flickering occurs on both versions.
The issue is isolated to Visual Studio and does not happen with any other applications.
The flickering only occurs on the screen where Visual Studio is displayed
like to video that show the problem  : https://streamable.com/ie3n6t
I have disable some options on VS :


Have you turned off Hardware Acceleration?

Your veed.io link says it's Private, so we can't view it.

@dai I have change the link, try now?

@day  what spesific to disable on visual studio about Hardware Acceleration ?
